# Adding index on jsonb field fail when running migration

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am using PostgreSQL with TypeORM. My `Student` entity has a `jsonb` field, defined like this:

```
@Entity('students')
export class Student {
  ...
  @Column('jsonb', { name: 'other_data', nullable: true })
  otherData: { nr?: string; hometown?: string } | null;
}
```

The `students` table was initially created without the column `other_data` but added later via the following migration:

```
await queryRunner.addColumns('students', [
      new TableColumn({
        name: 'other_data',
        type: 'jsonb',
        isNullable: true,
      }),
    ]);
```

The column adding was successful, I can see on psql console that `\d students` has the field with type `jsonb`.

The content of `otherData` is expected to be a json contains `nr` and `hometown` optional fields.

After database table is created, I try to run a migration to add index to the `nr` field of `otherData` (please bear in mind `otherData` is a `jsonb` type).

This is what I tried in TypeORM migration file:

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(
      `CREATE INDEX "student_nr" ON "students" USING gin (other_data -> 'nr')`
    );
```

When I run the migration, I get error:

```
Migration "AddIndexOnOtherDataColumn1647948281597" has been failed, error: syntax error at or near "->"
query: ROLLBACK
Error during migration run:
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "->"
    at QueryFailedError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (/Users/john/myproj/src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
    at new QueryFailedError (/Users/john/myproj/src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (/Users/john/myproj/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:247:19)
    at step (/Users/john/myproj/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.throw (/Users/john/myproj/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
    at rejected (/Users/john/myproj/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  query: `CREATE INDEX "student_nr" ON "students" USING gin (other_data -> 'nr')`,
  parameters: undefined,
  driverError: error: syntax error at or near "->"
```

The noticeable part of the error message is `parameters: undefined` and `error near "->"`. But I get stuck on why this error, where am I wrong?

Comment: have you tried putting the other_data like this "other_data" or 'other_data' ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, when add double quotation around `other_data`, the error would be `QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "->"`, when add single quotation around, it would produce the error `QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "'other_data'"`

Comment: Could you post the DDL of the created table?

Comment: The table creation doesn't include the `other_data`,  the `other_data` column is added later on via another migration.  I updated my post with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by adding one more `()` around `other_data->'nr'`:

```
await queryRunner.query(
      `CREATE INDEX "student_nr" ON "students" USING gin ((other_data -> 'nr'))`
    );
```

But it would be nice if someone is experienced with it could verify whether I am right in fixing the issue & also would be nice to explain more on it. Thanks!